# Upgraded to libcurl4 and broke apache?

Tags: apache2

Apache2 and Apache2-bin seem to depend on libcurl3. How can I get them to install now that I upgraded to libcurl4?

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-bin : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.28.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Upgraded to libcurl4 how exactly?  Which software distribution (Debian based?)  and what version?

Comment: Debian 10. I don't recall how I upgraded to libcurl4.

Comment: What are your apt sources?

Comment: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main

Comment: The version of `apache2-bin` shipped with Debian 10 (version 2.4.38-3+deb10u4) requires `libcurl4 (>= 7.16.2)`. An `apache2-bin` dependent on `libcurl3` does not appear in any official Debian version. Check also if you don't have any additional sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and perform an `apt update`.

Comment: In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apache2.list`, it has `deb https://packages.sury.org/apache2/ stretch main` Should I change `strecth` to `buster`? Is there a way to automatically change all of these files to `buster`?